# CSS, HTML issue. How would I get the main body of the document to be a certain way down from the top?

Tags: html, css, positioning, css-position, spacing

Basically I have a navbar and a title, that both have the properties, 
    position: fixed;
    top: (VALUE I INSERTED);
My problem is that obviously when I write the main body of the document the text is underneath the title/navbar. I need to get the text to be underneath the title and navbar, but without it having a fixed position. If any more information with code is needed, just comment saying so.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: but if you would like to see the code you can

Comment: actually that's what I'm looking for

Comment: actually, you can see the site that would be fine: http://www.fredhill.co.uk/about.php

Comment: @menislici is this what you were looking for?

Comment: @orano10000 I have changed my answer. Just check it. You ll get a whole new way of measuring things on web page. Hope its useful for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

apply to your main content area

```
#content {
    margin-top: YOUR HEADER HEIGHT
}
```

Comment: my header height? you mean my title? or navbar

Comment: I mean all your fixed elements combined height

Comment: ok thanks a lot I'm accepting this answer as soon as I can :-)

Answer (score 1):

The best way you can do that is to have the entire site after the bar what you call the main body in a Container like div. This would give you freedom to manipulate it as well as customize it to your needs in future.

For measuring the height in Pixels. Install the [web developers extension for firefox](http://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/) And then restart firefox and Click on the option pointed by image below and use the ruler for that.

Click on Miscellaneous as shown and activate 'DISPLAY RULER' 
[image]

Then Click and drag to measure and take the height and width as represented

[image]

Comment: So what css styles would I apply to the div?

Comment: `margin-top:Your header height along with nav bar` @orano10000 This would solve it.

Comment: OK, thanks a lot, is there any way I can measure the height in pixels?

Comment: @orano10000 I have mentioned how to measure. Please have a look. You can use this in various scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, wrap the main content area in a div (e.g id="wrapper",), then apply the css:

the html will look like so:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<p class="title">About</p>
<h6 class="bottom"><marquee>This page is the about page of 'Fred's Page'</marquee></h6>
<p class="body">Main body of document. At the moment it's in a fixed position.</p>
</div>
```

and the css:

```
#wrapper{
margin-top: 25px; //your actual navigation bar height. (as @Zoltan Toth suggested)
}
```

Comment: OK, thanks menislici for staying with me :) as I asked shiv kumar ganesh, is there any way i can measure the height in pixels?

Comment: yep i guessed the html, just a basic div tag with the id, I'm also assuming using a class instead is ok?

Comment: btw, I found your navbar value to be 25px thanks to inspect element option in chrome contextual menu, but you can use different tools as well, such as [firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/) for mozilla

Comment: ok thanks, the only thing is i need the pixel number to include the title and that spacing too but I guess I'll just slowly measure it :D